# Implement ICollectionView with support for Grouping

Tags: c#, grouping, icollectionview

I'm currently working on trying to implement Grouping in a VirtualCollection. Are there any Tutorials what and how I need to implent of ICollectionView so that Grouping with the DataGrid (in WPF and SL) works?

Project I work on: https://github.com/jogibear9988/VirtualCollection

Comment: Have you searched the internet first?

Comment: Yes... I found many Examples how to use a Collection View for Grouping but not how to implement it in a CustomCollection View

Answer (score 0):

Jochen,

The following links will be helpful for you.

[Sample Project - Using ICollectionViewLiveShaping](https://github.com/dotnetcurry/wpf45-live-shaping)

[Intro about ICollectionViewLiveShaping from the available .Net 4.5 feature](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/10/05/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-10-live-shaping/)